# Problems getting methods to be called

Tags: java, arrays

I can't seem to get the coordinatesAbove and percentageAbove to output anything. I have a method List<> coordinatesAbove which takes an altitude and puts the latitude and longitude in the List. I then need to work out the percentage of all the coordinates I have in the new List compared to the old List. I have this below. Whenever I run this, I can't seem to get the percentage to input.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

public class Map {

static double[][] array;
double longitude, latitude;
double alti;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Map m = new Map();
    m.readDataArray("earth.xyz");
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
    m.coordinatesAbove(-2000);
    m.percentageAbove(-2000);
    System.out.println(percentage);
}

public void readDataArray(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    int countLines = 0;
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        countLines++;
        input.nextLine();
    }
    array = new double[2336041][3];
    input.close();
    input = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    String curLine;
    double longitude, latitude;
    double alti;
    countLines = 0;
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        curLine = input.nextLine();
        String[] curData = curLine.split("\t");
        longitude = Double.parseDouble(curData[0]);
        latitude = Double.parseDouble(curData[1]);
        alti = Double.parseDouble(curData[2]);
        array[countLines][0] = longitude;
        array[countLines][1] = latitude;
        array[countLines][2] = alti;
        countLines++;
    }
}

public List<Double> coordinatesAbove(double altitude){
    List<Double> coordinatesAbove = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        coordinatesAbove.add(array[i][2]);
    }
    coordinatesAbove.removeIf(a -> a < altitude);
    return coordinatesAbove;
}

public double percentageAbove(double altitude) {
    double percentage = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (coordinatesAbove(-2000).contains(array[i][2]))
            percentage = percentage + 100 / array.length;
    }
    return percentage;
}
}
```

Comment: can you share the import statements too ??

Comment: This code won't compile.  You seem to be struggling with variable scope?  Take a read of this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/

Comment: Hi, I've added the import statements to this

Comment: Also, when you have problems like this, it's a good idea to print out the values of variables at each step along the way.  Many times your assumption about the value of a variable or where the problem really is will be wrong, and the print statements will help you find the real problem.

Comment: *"Whenever I run this"* - Attempting to run this code will result in at least one compiler error.  That error is a significant hint about what you've missed.  Did you read the error message?

Comment: Hi @David the error I'm getting is a NullPointerException error on ```for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfEarth.length; i++) { ``` on the coordinatesBelow method, could this be something to do with no accessing the file

Comment: @d_johnstone: That implies that the code you're showing us isn't the code you're using.  You can't be getting a runtime error from code that doesn't compile in the first place, and this line is a compiler error: `System.out.println(percentage);`  Since the variable `percentage` is never defined in that scope.  (Additionally... `e` is never defined in that scope, `coordinatesAbove` is missing its opening curly brace, and the class is missing its closing curly brace.)

Comment: Hi @David, I followed Elliott Frisch advice so I'm now defying the correct variable. The code is now able to compile but it now has the above error message. I've also put my code in a new package just to check its not part of my other code and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @d_johnstone Search this page for `arrayOfEarth`. The first time it appears is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61324553/problems-getting-methods-to-be-called/61324654?noredirect=1#comment108486718_61324553). Could be because there is no such array. You need to step back and ***carefully*** examine all of the errors your compiler reports.

Comment: Hi @ElliottFrisch, Sorry I think I may be confusing you all, I do have this as ```for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { ``` but I'm sure if the array.length is reading the earth.xyz file on the percentagesAbove method correctly as I'm getting the NullPointException error.

Comment: Well fix the NullPointException error then. Looking at your code - `array = new double[2336041][3];` should be `array = new double[countLines][3];` and if there are more errors you need to tell us **where** they are - the stack trace tells you **exactly** what line the error happened on. Also, now is a great time to learn to use a debugger. And reflect on how fortunate you are to have such a tool. [Old school debugging](https://americanhistory.si.edu/collections/search/object/nmah_334663) was seldom as pleasant.

Comment: Ok I will have a look at this is more detail, I'm quite new to java so I'm sorry if I'm not making much sense. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 3):

Your method returns the result, but you don't assign it anywhere.

```
m.percentageAbove(-2000);
```

should be

```
double percentage = m.percentageAbove(-2000);
```